# Email notification (format the email body) in java

Tags: java

How I can format the body content(string) of the email notification ( add color, make the text readable from left to right or right to left, spaces).

notice that I use Web service in order to send email in my web application.

This method in my backbean:

```
public void sendNotification() {
    IIMDelegate iimDelegate = new IIMDelegate();

    String toEmail = userInfoDto.getUserEmailAddress();
    String employeeName = userInfoDto.getUserName();
    String ideaTitle = addIdeaDto.getTitle();
    String ideaTimeDate = getCurrentTimeUsingCalendar();


    String emailBody = "Text Example"+" "+employeeName+" "+"Text Example"+" "+"Text Example"+" "+"Text Example"+" "+ideaTitle+" "+"Text Example"+" "+ideaTimeDate+" "+"Text Example"+" "+"Text Example";

    iimDelegate.sendNotification("senderMail", "senderName", toEmail,
            "ccEmail", "bccEmail", "mailTitle", emailBody,
            "");
}
```

I want email body (string) to be formatted like readable from right to left and have color:

```
String emailBody = "Text Example"+" "+employeeName+" "+"Text Example"+" "+"Text Example"+" "+"Text Example"+" "+ideaTitle+" "+"Text Example"+" "+ideaTimeDate+" "+"Text Example"+" "+"Text Example";
```

Thank you in advance,

I try to do this in order to format the email body without using the template:

```
  final String emailBody = String.join(
                System.getProperty("line.separator"),
                "<div>example</div>", employeeName,
                "<div>example</div>",
                "<div>:example</div>",
                "<div>example</div>",ideaTitle,
                "<div>example</div>",ideaTimeDate,
                "<div>example</div>",
                "<div>.example</div>");
```

the text (email body) is shows orderly but now I want to keep the text written or showing from right to left (align to right).

any comments!

Comment: Does your webservice allow you to send html?

Comment: Otherwise, there's nothing you can do

Comment: @Maurice Perry yes we can send html

Comment: Alright, then that's what you should do

Comment: I would recommend you to generate the body from a template, using a tool like velocity.

Comment: @Maurice I will read about velocity

Comment: @Maurice there is no way to generate a template from Eclipse ?

Comment: Well the template could basically be an html file with scriplets in it, so you could edit it in eclipse with syntax highlighting and all, but I'm not aware of any wysiwyg editor (for eclipse).

Comment: @Maurice do you have any links that will help me in using Velocity?

Comment: the user guide is here: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html

Comment: I update my post, any comment or help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at documentation of **IIMDelegate** class. Check if there is a way to send HTML email body.

Comment: `"Check if there is a way to send HTML email body"` <-- this part out your answer makes this not an answer but a comment.

Comment: I answer this up, we can send html

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you to take a look at https://freemarker.apache.org/

You can create a div with your message,(align,text colors everything!) and push in your data to the standard template. Well documented here , https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html

Good luck!